# Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ add Queue argument

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

I would like to know how to add extra arguments to a rabbitmq queue declared with spring cloud stream.

I want to use the Single Active Consumer feature for **RabbitMQ 3.8.x**. To do that I have to add an extra argument to the queue declaration `x-single-active-consumer`.
There is no way to configure it directly with spring properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting arbitrary queue arguments is not currently supported by spring cloud stream.

Please open a [GitHub issue against the binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues) to request a new feature.

However, you can simply declare the queue by adding a `Queue` `@Bean` to the application with the argument set.

Or, you can simply set the `exclusive` consumer binder properties, which provides similar semantics; the competing consumers will periodically attempt to reconnect.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So59011707Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59011707Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("so59011707.myGroup")
                .withArgument("x-single-active-consumer", true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend("so59011707", "", "foo");
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=so59011707
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=myGroup
```

You will see an error message in the log

> 2019-11-24 10:24:22.310 ERROR 83004 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-single-active-consumer' for queue 'so59011707.myGroup' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'true' of type 'bool', class-id=50, method-id=10)

which you can ignore. Or you can avoid it by setting `bindQueue` to false and add `Exchange` and `Binding` `@Bean`s as well...

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bind-queue=false
```

```
@Bean
Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue())
            .to(exchange())
            .with("#");
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("so59011707");
}
```

Comment: is there any example to configure a `Queue` as a `@Bean` and still use the capabilities added by spring cloud stream such as `@StreamListener` and `@SendTo`?

Comment: I created the new feature request [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/274)